# i want to show all list items instead of one item

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, onclick

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mango.css">
        <script>
            function mango(){
                document.getElementById("apple").style.display="block";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <ul id="main" onclick="mango()">main1
        <li id="apple">sub1</li>
         <li id="apple">sub2</li>
         <li id="apple">sub3</li>
    </ul>
     <ul id="main">main2
        <li>sub11</li>
         <li>sub2</li>
         <li>sub11</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

associated CSS:

```
#main li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: none;
}
```

in the given program, when i click on main1 which on display the first list item,instead of that i want to display all list items under that.can you help me?

Comment: you cannot use duplicate id. Id needs to be unique. Use class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have replaced the id with class and changed the js accordingly. Using multiple id with same value will result in undesired behavior depending on browsers

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mango.css">
        <script>
            function mango(){
                document.querySelectorAll(".apple")
                    .forEach(function(node){
                        node.style.display="block";
                    })                        
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <ul id="main" onclick="mango()">main1
        <li class="apple">sub1</li>
         <li class="apple">sub2</li>
         <li class="apple">sub3</li>
    </ul>
     <ul id="main">main2
        <li>sub11</li>
         <li>sub2</li>
         <li>sub11</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```